# Same DLL accessed by two applets in 2 web applications

Tags: java, dll, applet, classloader, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I need a suggestion to solve the following problem.

I have two web applications (let's say WEBAPP-A and WEBAPP-B) running under the same application server. Each login page in each application page activates a specific applet
(let's call them JAPP-A and JAPP-B, respectively). These two applets need to use the same DLL.

Each applet (JAPP-A or JAPP-B) works OK when accessing the application separately (in our case the browser used is Internet Explorer 8.0 and the JRE version of the client is 1.7.0_45). However, when redirecting from WEBAPP-A to WEBAPP-B, the applet JAPP-B crashes.

I get the error:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'DLL already loaded in another classloader'
```

So I have tried to use the same classloader for JAPP-A and JAPP-B by setting the same CODEBASE value inside the applet tag and deploying the JAR containing the JAPP-B code under the CODEBASE path, but we got the same error message.

Can anyone suggest an alternative approach in order to get the applet JAPP-B working correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Deploy each applet in it's own Java Virtual Machine.  E.G. from [Applet Deployment Parameters: `separate_jvm`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#SEPARATE_JVM).

```html
<APPLET archive="my_applet.jar" code="MyApplet" width="300" height="300">
    <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="...">
    <!-- use a separate JVM for this applet! -->
    <PARAM name="separate_jvm" value="true">
</APPLET>
```

Comment: It would also pay to look into launching the applets using JNLP/Java Web Start, since that makes deploying natives much simpler.

Comment: So, did this solve the problem for you?  Are you till thinking about it?